# how to send tcp packets between 2 hosts on same network

Tags: ping, acl, mininet

iam using mininet network simulation tool and i need to send tcp packets between 2 host hosts are 10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2 ,i used the hping3 but is sends ip packets also i used this command 
hping3 -c 1 [destination ip address]   but didn't work for me 
[image]

Comment: TCP segments are contained in IP packets.

Comment: If you're looking for hping commands, try this: https://cyberwar.nl/d/cheatsheets/hping3_cheatsheet_v1.0-ENG.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `hping3` uses TCP. TCP segments use IP for network transport which in turn uses Ethernet for the link layer.

When 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2 are connected to the same switch (or VLAN) they should be able to "see" each other and transmit directly. If that doesn't work the intermediate switches' configurations, the hosts' links, and their subnet masks - /30 or shorter places them in the same subnet and should work.